# ConvertFrom-JSON to variables for POST further on to PowerBI

Tags: powershell, api, powerbi-datasource

I am fetching API data from a URL which is formatted as below:

```json
{
  "printers" : [ {
    "name" : "printsrv01\\printer01",
    "status" : "OK",
    "lastPrintJobSeconds" : 6495,
    "heldJobsCount" : 0,
    "physicalPrinterId" : "net://192.168.0.51"
  }, {
    "name" : "printsrv01\\printer02",
    "status" : "OK",
    "heldJobsCount" : 0,
    "physicalPrinterId" : "net://192.168.0.52"
  }, {
    "name" : "printsrv02\\printer03",
    "status" : "OK",
    "heldJobsCount" : 0,
    "physicalPrinterId" : "net://192.168.0.53"
  }, {
    "name" : "printsrv01\\printer04",
    "status" : "OK",
    "heldJobsCount" : 0,
    "physicalPrinterId" : "net://192.168.0.54"
  }, {
    "name" : "printsrv02\\printer05",
    "status" : "OK",
    "heldJobsCount" : 0,
    "physicalPrinterId" : "net://192.168.0.55"
  }, {
    "name" : "printsrv01\\printer06",
    "status" : "OK",
    "lastPrintJobSeconds" : 183162,
    "heldJobsCount" : 0,
    "physicalPrinterId" : "net://192.168.0.56"
  } ],
  "heldJobCountTotal" : 0,
  "heldJobsCountMax" : 0
}
```

I have managed to convert the data from JSON using following code:

```bsh
while ($true) {
    $request = "http://serveradress:80/api/health/printers?Authorization=GHSKAskas0a5as5FFDA22asD"
    Invoke-WebRequest  $request |
        ConvertFrom-Json |
        select -Expand printers |
}
```

I am using PowerBI where I would like to upload the data.
This can be done using the below code if my values are stored in variables.

```bsh
$payload = @{
    "name" = $name
    "status" = $status
    "lastPrintJobSeconds" = $lastPrintJobSeconds
    "heldJobsCount" = $heldJobsCount
    "physicalPrinterId" = $physicalPrinterId
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json @($payload))
```

How can I put each printer information in each variable to send it to the PowerBI datasource used for display?

---

**Edit:**

I tried to use the solution suggested by [@TheldesOfMark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58731359/1630171):

```bsh
$endpoint = "https://api.powerbi.com/beta/aaa555v22-66888-ccc6-95aa-0dfb5dc31330/datasets/aaa555a666-6547-4250-950c-25s5sd5s5s5s5/rows?key=65asd55asd45asd45asd5as5d4!%54dsa5f45fc4zd56fc4"

while ($true) {
    $request = "http://server:80/api/health/printers?Authorization=asd54asas5dSSd55sd4as65d4ASDA"
    Invoke-WebRequest  $request |
        ConvertFrom-Json |
        select -Expand printers |

    foreach ($printer in $printers) {
        $payload = @{
            "name" = $printer.name
            "status" = $printer.status
            "lastPrintJobSeconds" = $printer.lastPrintJobSeconds
            "heldJobsCount" = $printer.heldJobsCount
            "physicalPrinterId" = $printer.physicalPrinterId
        }
        Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json @($payload))
        Write-Host "Name: " $printer.name " Status: " $printer.status " lastPrintJobSeconds: " $printer.lastPrintJobSeconds " heldJobsCount: " $printer.heldJobsCount " physicalPrinterId: " $printer.physicalPrinterId
    }
    sleep 2
}
}
```

but it generates the following errors:

```
At line:10 char:22
+     foreach ($printer in $printers) {
+                       ~~
Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement.
At line:10 char:21
+     foreach ($printer in $printers) {
+                      ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At line:4 char:1
+ {
+ ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At line:10 char:34
+     foreach ($printer in $printers) {
+                                   ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:22 char:5
+     }
+     ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

It seems like the `foreach` loop is the issue?
If I don't convert from JSON it doesn´t give any errors but I doesn't get any data out if I try without converting first.

**Edit 2**

Changed the Invoke-WebRequest to below and Write Output works it print the data correct.
But I get error on the Invoke-RestMethod:

```bsh
$printers = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://server:80/api/health/printers?Authorization=asd54asas5dSSd55sd4as65d4ASDA' | ConvertFrom-Json | select -Expand printers
```

The errorcode is as followed:

```bsh
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"message":"The request was blocked by KeyBlocker "}}
At line:14 char:9
+         Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json @( ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

***Edit 3***

```bsh
$endpoint = "PowerBI_URL"
Invoke-WebRequest 'API_URL' |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    Select-Object -Expand printers |
    ForEach-Object {
        Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" (ConvertTo-Json @($_))
    }
```

Error code:

```bsh
Invoke-RestMethod : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '[
    {
        "name":  "printsrv01\\printer01",
        "status":  "OK",
        "heldJobsCount":  0,
        "physicalPrinterId":  "net://192.168.0.51"
    }
]'.
At line:6 char:9
+         Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" (ConvertTo-Json @($_))
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Not all values seems to be printed. Missing some.

***Edit 4 - Working script***

```
$endpoint = "https://api.powerbi.com/beta/nnf5d2dsf1-4588-88gh-b6a4-0dfb5dc31330/datasets/55562ee92-9c7d-8850-854g-1a39asdd8a4b/rows?key=ljrethjkreRDFG545REWFGGDF0DFGDGF"

while ($true) {
    $printers = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://server/api/health/printers?Authorization=sdfkjdsf044s21sDSFsdf54sdf' | ConvertFrom-Json | select -Expand printers

    foreach ($printer in $printers) {
        $payload = @{
            "name" = $printer.name
            "status" = $printer.status
            "lastPrintJobSeconds" = $printer.lastPrintJobSeconds
            "heldJobsCount" = $printer.heldJobsCount
            "physicalPrinterId" = $printer.physicalPrinterId
        }
        Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json @($payload))
        #Write-Host "Name: " $printer.name " Status: " $printer.status " lastPrintJobSeconds: " $printer.lastPrintJobSeconds " heldJobsCount: " $printer.heldJobsCount " physicalPrinterId: " $printer.physicalPrinterId
        sleep 1
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're getting errors from an attempt to apply something suggested in an answer and want that clarified in the context of your current question, please avoid editing the question in a way that would invalidate other answers given to the original question. In this case appending the modified code and errors works. In other cases posting a followup question might be warranted.

Comment: As for the new errors you're getting: `foreach` loops are different from `ForEach-Object` and do not read from the pipeline. To make the code work you need to remove the trailing `|` from the pipeline and collect the pipeline output in a variable `$printers`.

Comment: I understand. I thought I needed to edit the existing code so that my question wasn't gonna be to long. I will check the pipeline tomorrow, thanks

Comment: New error occurs about some Keyblocker. Added the error code above.

Comment: That seems to be a server response. Are you sure the API (including authentication) works the way you expect it to?

Comment: I can view the data in the browser. The same upload method is tested and worked just fine with my computer data from powershell.
(I also tested your script to see if that worked better and after I edited it some it also prints data but with error and it doesn't upload)

Comment: Your browser may or may not do things that `Invoke-WebRequest` doesn't. That doesn't mean anything unless you have verified that the requests sent by either client are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansgar's answer is the best answer, in my opinion. But in case there's some reason you need to have this information available to other PS processes. You can cast the variables from your current script by just looping through the array you built and assigning the variables.

```
ForEach($printer in $printers){
    $payload = @{
        "name" = $printer.name
        "status" = $printer.status
        "lastPrintJobSeconds" = $printer.lastPrintJobSeconds
        "heldJobsCount" = $printer.heldJobsCount
        "physicalPrinterId" = $printer.physicalPrinterId
    }
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json @($payload))
}
```

Comment: I agree Ansgards code is more neat. But I would like to place each value in separate variabel as you wrote.
When I try your code I get some errors in the for each loop. I updated my code above

Comment: Managed with your script.
Had one issue at the database whioch I tried to store the data as numeric when it contained character. Fixed that and now my Edit 4 is the working code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

AFAICS you don't need to extract the individual values into distinct variables. Simply add a `ForEach-Object` to your pipeline where you convert the current object to JSON and invoke the POST request with that.

```
Invoke-WebRequest $request |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    Select-Object -Expand printers |
    ForEach-Object {
        $data = ConvertTo-Json $_
        Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $endpoint -Body $data
    }
```